# Can I install Docker by windows 8.1?

Tags: docker

I want to deploy a web app with .NET Core 3.1 to Heroku using Docker and I Download it then said to me should use Windows 10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Docker for Windows require Windows 10.
If you use an older version of Windows like Windows 8.1, you should use [Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/) instead. It's a legacy solution for older windows and mac.

For that, you will need to install VirtualBox and you need to keep in mind that docker will run inside a VM. If you start and expose a container port, you can't connect on it using localhost but, instead, the VM IP.